# Javascript new row function do not render other Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, html-table

I am displaying a table with texbox inside, where certain texboxes have datepicker class that render a calender. 
I am trying to add a row inside a table by clicking a link provided. I can add the row but the new texboxes inside the row do not display the datepicker calender.

```
    jQuery(function(){
      var counter = 5;
      jQuery('a.sumJobs').click(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          counter++;
          var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td>'+ counter +'</td><td><input type="text" name="designation[]" id="employer3" /></td><td><input name="from[]" type="text" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" id="from'+ counter +'" /></td' +
              counter + '><td><input name="to[]" type="text" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" id="to'+ counter +'" /></td>' +
              counter + '<td><input type="text" name="totalexp[]" id="totalexp" /></td></tr>');
          jQuery('table.sumJobs').append(newRow);
      });
  });

  $(function() {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
          changeMonth: true
          ,changeYear: true
          ,yearRange: '1960:' + new Date().getFullYear()
        });
    });
```

Here is the link that renders a new row

```
<a href="#" title="" class="sumJobs"><center>Add another experience</center></a>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you use both `$` and `jQuery` and have two document ready handlers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$(".datepicker")
```

You are selecting all the elements that have the `datepicker` class that currently exist in the DOM. What you are *not* doing is selecting elements that might have the `datepicker` class that exist some time later.

So what you will need to do after creating a new row is select the child element and apply `.datapicker` to it again.

You could probably just do something like:

```
newRow.find(".datepicker").datepicker({
    //...your configuration goes here
});
```

After you create the newRow.

To avoid a lot of duplication, I'd just store the parameters for datepicker in a variable somewhere:

```
var pickerOptions = {
      changeMonth: true
      ,changeYear: true
      ,yearRange: '1960:' + new Date().getFullYear()
}
```

So then you can just do:

```
newRow.find(".datepicker").datepicker(pickerOptions);
```

So you could wrap it all up like this:

```
$(function(){
    var counter = 5;
    $('a.sumJobs').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        counter++;
        var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td>'+ counter +'</td><td><input type="text" name="designation[]" id="employer3" /></td><td><input name="from[]" type="text" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" id="from'+ counter +'" /></td' +
          counter + '><td><input name="to[]" type="text" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" id="to'+ counter +'" /></td>' +
          counter + '<td><input type="text" name="totalexp[]" id="totalexp" /></td></tr>');
        $('table.sumJobs').append(newRow);
        newRow.find(".datepicker").datepicker(pickerOptions);
    });

    var pickerOptions = {
        changeMonth: true
        ,changeYear: true
        ,yearRange: '1960:' + new Date().getFullYear()
    };

    // if there are no .datepicker elements at the start, you don't actually need the following line
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker(pickerOptions);
});
```

Comment: Please can you set an example code. I am not very good with javascript. thank YOu

Comment: I mean I dunno where to put the code you type. I need to know area to put code. And what configuration do I have to put inside newRow function. I am a PHP beginner trying my luck with JS.

Comment: @Xia: I told you pretty clearly where to put it when I said "*After you create the newRow.*".

Comment: Yes thank you. 
I added that to the table but it is still not adding a calender to newly added texboxes in the row. Here is the link for demo. 
http://irsp.org.pk/jobs/indexn.php

Comment: Wow you did it. The hasDatepicker was getting duplicated. I am so pleased. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the id of the new input:

`...
jQuery('table.sumJobs').append(newRow);
$("#to" + counter).datepicker({
          changeMonth: true
          ,changeYear: true
          ,yearRange: '1960:' + new Date().getFullYear()
        });`

Maybe you could have a function like

```
function createCalendar(element){  
element.datepicker({
    changeMonth: true
    ,changeYear: true
    ,yearRange: '1960:' + new Date().getFullYear()
});
```

}